# EWS - Access Shared Calendars

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I would like to list the permission from every exchange shared calendar.
I have two exchange online account :
vikramsingh@gmail.com
vikramsinghmrt@outlook.com

Now, i have shared a calendar to vikramsinghmrt@outlook.com from vikramsingh@gmail.com.

Now when i fetch the calendar list using Exchange EWS API, i got all calendar (include shared calendar), But there is no way to know that which one shared calendar.

I have use below code :

PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, FolderSchema.Permissions);
       Folder folder = Folder.Bind(service, folderid, propSet);

```
   if (folder.Permissions.Count != 0)
    {
        for (int t = 0; t < folder.Permissions.Count; t++)
        {
            if (folder.Permissions[t].UserId.DisplayName != null || folder.Permissions[t].UserId.PrimarySmtpAddress != null)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

But this return userId.DisplayName  and UserId.PrimarySmtpAddress   to null every time.

How could i know that which calendar is SHARED ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. We have calendar call as below. service.FindFolders(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root, "email")

In this call we pass my email id. (My credential email).
If i need to access other user calendar(Shared calendar). I need to pass other user email address here. like service.FindFolders(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root, "Other user email").

Service object is created by my credential and just pass email of other user. Now you can get all calendar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the properties `RequiredAttendees` and `OptionalAttendees` and check for the E-Mail address of the shared calendar. If one of the properties containts the mail address of the shared calendar, it is from the shared calendar.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Folder Associated Items collection of each folder using an Associated Traversal for Shared folders there should be an Item of Type IPM.Sharing.SyncState within that collection.

```
        ItemView iv = new ItemView(1000);
        iv.Traversal = ItemTraversal.Associated;
        SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ItemSchema.ItemClass, "IPM.Sharing.SyncState");
        FindItemsResults<Item> fiItems = Folder.FindItems(sf, iv);
```